# How to "paint" on JLabels on a JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, graphics2d, paintcomponent

I have a set of `JLabel`s, each containing a letter (via seText()), opaque and background set to white, on a `JPanel` with a `GridLayout` so the labels are forming a table.
I am doing a simple animation of highlighting certain rows and columns then there intersection. I can use the `setBackground()` of labels for this purpose, but thought I'd have more "choices" if a was able to use a `Graphics` object (maybe drawing a circle around intersection, then clearing it).
I tried to extend `JLabel`, or drawing on the `JPanel` directly(using `getGraphics()` in a method) but it didn't work, I think the drawing is behind the labels in this case. I can't figure out where should the "painting" code be placed in either case, nothing appeared on the screen.

in short, a method like the following, can be used to draw on top of labels?
should it be a JLabel or a JPanel method?

```
public void drawsomething() {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) getGraphics();
    g2d.fillRect(100, 100, 100, 100);
    }
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure exactly what affect you're trying to achieve but it sounds as if you'd be best served by drawing in the JLabel's `paintComponent(...)` method. Why not create an [sscce](http://sscce.org) and show us what you've tried?

Comment: What is it I am getting wrong? please edit your question with a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Speficially express what you are trying to do instead of telling a long story please.

Comment: sorry for the long story, wasn't intended.

Comment: whatever you do in the end, _do not_ use getGraphics

Comment: why not? what's the problem with getGraphics?

Comment: @kleopatra, unless you explain why, your comment is indeed rather empty...

Comment: @dm76 - no, it's far from empty: it's a pointer to type "+swing +getgraphics" into the search field above and click on the first result that comes up ... or do you complain about the missing explicit mention of swing in my comment?

Comment: @kleopatra, I'm not complaining about anything. I'm just saying that generic comments like "don't do this, don't do that" are not useful in their form. Something along the lines "be aware of getGraphics, see discussion [link]" is a lot more informative of what you're trying to convey

Comment: @dm76 not really. For a successful developer, the very first reflex an receiving a Dont or Do _must_ be a search. After all, this forum _is_ a QA type forum, designed to be searched. Playing further: your comments might be considered even emptier than mine: they are mere opinions, without even being at the slightest related to the content of the question ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What if you override `paintChildren()` ?

```
protected void paintChildren(Graphics g) {
  super.paintChildren(g);
//paint your lines here
}
```

Comment: if I placed the drawing code in the JPanel's paintChildren() the drawing will show. But what if I wanted to paint and delete upon a method call, how can I get the children graphic context outside of paintChildren()? Or should I place the painting code in paintChildren() and rely on conditions for drawing/deleting each time?

Comment: I am not sure what you would like to achieve but you can paint all your content in a BufferedImage and use it.

Comment: I am just trying to be able to write methods that can draw on a grid of JLabels, drawSomething(x, y) for example, and clearing it (as part of animation).
By "using" the BufferedImage you mean, adding it to the panel after drawing?

Comment: your drawSomething(x,y) can be relatively easily achieved with a JLayeredPane, see my own answer

Answer (score 3):

You might want to try a JLayeredPane to paint your specific drawings on top of the existing JComponents

see example here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html

Answer (score 2):

I really don't know much about drawing stuff yet, but just created one small sample code for you to look at, hopefully you can get some information out of it. In order to paint on the `JLabel you can use it's paintComponent(Graphics g)` method.

A Sample Code :

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class DrawingOnJLabel extends JFrame
{
    private CustomLabel label;
    private int flag = 1;
    private JPanel contentPane;

    public DrawingOnJLabel()
    {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        label = new CustomLabel(200, 200);
        label.setLabelText("A");
        label.setValues(50, 50, 100, 100, 240, 60);

        final JButton button = new JButton("CLEAR");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
            {
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
                {
                    public void run()
                    {
                        if (flag == 1)              
                        {
                            label.setFlag(flag);
                            flag = 0;
                            button.setText("REPAINT");
                            contentPane.revalidate();
                            contentPane.repaint();
                        }   
                        else if (flag == 0) 
                        {
                            label.setFlag(flag);
                            flag = 1;
                            button.setText("CLEAR");
                            contentPane.revalidate();
                            contentPane.repaint();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });     

        contentPane.add(label);

        add(contentPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(button, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        setSize(300, 300);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                new DrawingOnJLabel();
            }
        });
    }
}

class CustomLabel extends JLabel
{
    private int sizeX;
    private int sizeY;
    private int x, y, width, height, startAngle, arcAngle;
    private int flag = 0;
    private String text;

    public CustomLabel(int sX, int sY)
    {
        sizeX = sX;
        sizeY = sY; 
    }

    // Simply call this or any set method to paint on JLabel.
    public void setValues(int x, int y, int width, int height, int startAngle, int arcAngle)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.startAngle = startAngle;
        this.arcAngle = arcAngle;
        repaint();
    }

    public void setFlag(int value)
    {
        flag = value;
        repaint();
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize()
    {
        return (new Dimension(sizeX, sizeY));
    }

    public void setLabelText(String text)
    {
        super.setText(text);
        this.text = text;
        flag = 0;
        repaint();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        if (flag == 0)
        {
            g.setColor(Color.RED);          
            g.drawString(text, 20, 20);
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g.drawOval(x, y, width, height);
            g.fillOval(x + 20, y + 20, 15, 15);
            g.fillOval(x + 65, y + 20, 15, 15);
            g.fillRect(x + 40, y + 40, 5, 20);
            g.drawArc(x + 20, y + 30, 55, 55, startAngle, arcAngle);            
        }
        else if (flag == 1)
        {
            g.clearRect(x, y, width, height);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Tommy: Glad the example helped. Thanks for appreciating and for the rest KEEP SMILING :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use paintComponent(Graphics g) instead of paint(Graphics g). That will paint over the GUI